# How to disable mypy error code at package level?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy

`variable=[]`

Error:

```
 error: Need type annotation for 'variable' (hint: "variable: List[<type>] = ...")
```

In config file: mypy.ini

> disallow_any_expr=False

Is there any way to override this error by a flag in config file?

Comment: Well, why don't you just add the type annotation instead of trying to silence errors?

Comment: I'm refactoring existing code base which has huge of no. of changes, so that's why.

Comment: Well, `# type: ignore` on the line, then...

Comment: @AKX even that needs to be changed at every lines and many files... i just wanted mypy checks for function typehints only... these things also getting inbetween

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this:

- run `mypy --show-error-code your_module.py`, which will output the error code inside square brackets
- in `mypy.ini`,  add `disable_error_code = code`